# unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int' error

Tags: python

Just started coding 2 days ago and decided to build a little BMI calculator, but I keep getting this error, I've tried everything I could find, but had no sucess, can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?
thanks in advance! [Image of my coding and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqjA3.png)

Comment: Please, [include code as text in the question instead of linking to an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Why `int(float` rather than just `int(`? A string doesn't need a journey through a float before it gets to an int.

Answer (score 1):

Your typecasting is not assigned to a variable and you need height and weight in float.

```
height = float(input("Enter your height in m: "))
weight = float(input("Enter your weight in kg: "))

BMI = weight / (height**2)
```

Comment: dang now that I realize this I feel stupid, thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
height = float(input(...))
weight = float(input(...))
```

You're not actually setting the result of `float()` to the variable.